# plotting triangle inside circle

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating a circle and want to then develop a right-angle triangle, or any isometric form of a triangle. Whereby, I can take any line distance between two edges of the circle and draw arrows toward the peak point.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
x1 = np.cos(theta) 
y1 = np.sin(theta) 

plt.plot(x1, y1)
for i in [min(y1), max(y1)]:
    plt.plot(0, i, '-ok', mfc='C1', mec='C1')
plt.arrow(0,min(y1),0,2*max(y1),width=0.001,color='red',head_starts_at_zero=False)
plt.arrow(min(x1), (1/2)*min(y1), 2*max(x1), (1/2)*max(y1),width=0.001,color='red',head_starts_at_zero=False)
```

However, I cannot accurately get the distance between two points correct when i aim for any form of a triangle.

[image]

However, I can easily achieve it when setting `y` to 0 in the second arrow. Perhaps there is a general equation to do this?

Comment: An equilateral triangle has points at 0 degrees, 120 degrees, and 240 degrees.  For a unit circle, `x = cos(theta)` and `y = sin(theta)`.  Do that for all three angles.  It's just that easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
x1 = np.cos(theta) 
y1 = np.sin(theta) 

plt.plot(x1, y1)

x = np.array([0,120,240,0])
y = np.array([0,120,240,0])
x = np.cos( x * np.pi / 180 )
y = np.sin( y * np.pi / 180 )

plt.plot( x, y, color='red' )
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

In fact, if you choose ANY three angles, you'll get an inscribed triangle.

Comment: And if you want a right angle triangle, you just have to make sure the difference between 2 of the angles is 180 ;)

Comment: @Swifty I had to read up on basic trigonometry to remember all of this!

Comment: Indeed, all always comes down to the basics ;)